# need to create a custom control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have below requirement:

I wanted to create a custom control in which developer should be able to access below three properties.

1. Label:
2. IsRequired
3. content.

Example 1: 
Name(Label): TextBox/any input control(Content)

Example 2: 
Name(Label)*(IsRequired): TextBox/any input control(Content)

1. Developer should be able to apply globalization to the Label
2. If the field is required then he should be able to set a property
   to enable * symbol
3. Developer should be able set any input control as a content of the control.

I request your suggestions, if you send me a sample code that would be good for me.

Comment: I think you should do some research on the subject and then ask some concrete questions.

Comment: You are showing a total lack of involvement and expect others to provide a solution for you. This is not going to work out

Answer (score 1):

[This demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17830/Creating-and-consuming-a-custom-WPF-control) doesn't seem latest but should be a good start. Googling around a bit more with the keywords found in the demo will also yield some relevant results.